# after i get the gps/network location android delete the value of the location

Tags: android

i trying to get the value of the location. 
I debugging the code and i see that after i get the location - the android studio is not return the value to the main activity

I see that there are no exception on the code.

The method 'getCurrentLocation' return the location. 
After i get the location from the gps/network ( right location accourding to the debug viewer ) i  see that the code just to the line

```
    'if (!isGpsEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {'
```

and return the null on the 'location' 
variable even that the 'location' variable contain the right gps location.

The code:

```
  public class TraceLocation implements LocationListener
 {
public Location getCurrentLocation(Context context)
{
    Location location = null;

    try {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Boolean isGpsEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Boolean isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGpsEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {
            // TODO !!! => no gps and no network !!!
        } else if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (isNetworkEnable) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }
            }

            if (isGpsEnable) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }


    return location;
}
```

**The question:**

- i using android 6.0 ( marshmallow )

  1. why i get null on the result when the method is back even when i see that the return value on the debug is not null
  2. when i remove the

     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, this);

and the

```
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, this);
```

I don't get and location on the debug also - why ?????

Comment: What exactly is your question? :) What are you trying to do? What do you need help one exactly? Please be specific. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description you provided, it seems to me that you have not completely implemented what is required by the native Android Location mechanism.
Location providers in Android work in an asynchronous way, so you have to register a listener that will be notified when location updates are generated.
You couldn't expect an immediate response of the system (unless you use the `getLastKnownLocation(String provider)` method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))).

Your class includes an `implements LocationListener`, which should have forced you to implement a series of methods, including `onLocationChanged(Location location)`.
Such method is the one that will be fired when a location is obtained; you could inspect the `location` object to see its origin (Wireless or GPS) and other data (speed, accuracy and so on).

Have a look on the official guide for more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).
Since your debugging operation is dealing with data collected from the environment (GPS and wireless networks) the behavior of the system will be depending on such variables.